# Render a web page using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html2canvas

Is it possible to pass the html of an entire document with all the computed styles to server to get PhantomJS render and save to a PNG? (similar to html2canvas)

What I'm trying to achieve is using PhantomJS to take a screenshot of a web page (in its current state). So things like modal dialog, clicked tabs will all be in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass computed styles since they are not present in the DOM. It is a property of the DOM nodes when CSS was applied. In order for this to work you need to make every style accessible to the server, for example when stylesheets are access controlled the server would need to additionally log in or something like that. This should be rarely the case though.

It would be probably enough to send

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

to the server and let PhantomJS render the received HTML

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
    page.render("page.png");
    phantom.exit();
};
page.content = "received HTML as string"
    .replace(/href="\/\//g, 'href="http://')
    .replace(/href=\/\//g, 'href=http://');
```

Sometimes resources (stylesheets) lack the protocol in its URL, but PhantomJS needs the http protocol when local pages are loaded (setting `page.content`) otherwise it will assume that the URL use `file://` instead of `http://`.

You may need to run PhantomJS with some commandline options like `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` or `--local-to-remote-url-access=true`.